# strange pitch direction

Tags: ros, joint, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I have some troubles understanding rpy. Here is my simple URDF file:

```
<robot name="test">
<link name="Body">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="4.0" />
    <origin xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="1" ixz="1" iyy="1" iyz="1" izz="1" />
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.1 0.02 0.02"/>
    </geometry>
    
  </visual>
</link>


<link name="link1">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="4.0" />
    <origin xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="1" ixy="1" ixz="1" iyy="1" iyz="1" izz="1" />
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.1 0.02 0.02"/>
    </geometry>
    
  </visual>

</link>


<joint name="j1" type="revolute" >
  <parent link="Body"/>
  <child link="link1"/>
  <origin xyz="0.1 0 0" rpy="0 -0.5 0" />
  <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="10"/>
</joint>


</robot>
```

As you see, there are two links with a revolute joint between them. There is a pitch of -0.5 radians in the joint.
And here is the rviz image :

[image: image description]

The question is why `link1` is rotated upwards instead of downwards?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261022/strange-pitch-direction/) by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You specify a *pitch* of -0.5 rads, this is a rotation around the y axis. The y axis is denoted in green. As (by convention) a right handed frame is used, you can use the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) to determine the direction or rotation. From what I can tell, the rotation on the picture is correct.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-05-06**:
thank you!